# Extraction of main content of an article (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, extract, html-content-extraction

I'm writing a program that reads a general HTML "article" page (Wikipedia, NY Times, Yahoo News, ect). From that page I want to strip away all of the "noise" (ads, header bars.. anything that isn't part of the article content.) 
To think about it another way, I want to keep the most important stuff. (Main content, Title, author)

I'm trying to come up with a clever way to find the main content of an article I have a few ideas but they aren't exactly what I want. 
I do not want to parse every node in the DOM. My current idea involves using the size of the elements.

Any ideas are appreciated. At its core, this is a design question.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your platform?  Browser?  node.js?  And, what does the content look like (we need to see the HTML)?  Scraping content from HTML does not have a generic solution.  All solutions are dependent upon understanding how the particular target site organizes its content.

Comment: You might be interested in reading more about the `<main>` and `<article>` HTML5 tags. More info: http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html

Comment: Also, why don't you use an HTML parser and then analyze the parsed document?  You're making the job hundreds of times harder if you're not going to parse the HTML.

Comment: Thanks @johnnyRose 
Your comment was the most helpful for HTML5 pages. 

Generic HTML4 scraping is pretty tough, but I'm still working on it.

Comment: Glad to hear! Hope you got it all figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I think setting up a parser by yourself is probably too complicated. Often there is poor markup with no semantic elements and other stuff.

What you could do is to use the [Parser API from Readability](https://www.readability.com/developers/api/parser). If you are using NodeJS you can do a http.get request, if you are using Javascript in the Browser you can make an ajax request to the API.

Comment: "Give Up" is not a valid option.
I'm doing this, its only a matter of how.

Comment: Of course you can do it. The same way I can build my own house, my own car or whatever. Just because I can do it in theory doesn't mean I have to do it in practice. That's why the Readability API might be of great use because you can use their expertise and instead concentrate on your actual product.